# Visual Studio 2015 enable MVC 4 support

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have an ASP NET MVC 4 project that "works on my machine(old)". When I load a project in a fresh installation of VS 2015(on a new laptop) - a lot of assemblies are missing and when I try to build the project it complains that classes like ActionResult, Controller are missing.

I checked that on the old laptop the missing dependencies are coming from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies`. On the new laptop I have only the xml descriptors of the packages but not the dlls.

What I have to install to use MVC 4 in Visual Studio 2015?

Edit: missing dependencies are:

- System.Web.Helpers
- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.WebPages
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor

Comment: List the Assemblies that are missing here.

Comment: @Valkyriee done, see edit.

Comment: You can always install asp.net 4 using Nuget

Comment: @EvgeniDimitrov see my answer :)

Comment: @EvgeniDimitrov if by any chance it didn't let you to install them again, you need to remove the package and install or Update them.

Comment: do you install update 3 for VS2015 ? It has major fixes and enhancements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Recommend getting them again from `Nuget` for your `ActionResult` Issue its `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` which is making issue.

Open Package Manager Console and insert the command below:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
```

Nuget has this feature that allows you to restore all the missing `Assemblies` which exists in nuget. you can try that out as well.

Anyway for the rest of them install these packages below as well:

- Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers
- Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages
- Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Razor

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have install [update 3 for VS2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs)

also check if Microsoft web developer tools are installed correctly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issues when using source control or moving projects from one PC to another.

There is a work around that I use quite often and it works.

1. Go to YourProjectFolder -> packages. 
   Remove all the folders except for the xml, repositories.xml, file which is the xml config file for packages downloaded from Nuget.
2. On your solution in Visual Studio Right click and select Enable Nuget Packages Restore.
3. Then build the application it will re-download all the required packages.
   Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For Me what solved the issue is to install `ASP.NET MVC 4 for Visual Studio 2010` from [Microsoft Web Page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683)